# Highlight item with same style as the dragged/clicked one

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a large number of items, each marked with a some class. There might be multiple items having the same class.

When an item is clicked or dragged I want to highlight all the items that have the same class.

I'd like to do that in a non-naïve way (e.g. not using JS to iterate through all items and adding the "highlighted" class to the items with matching class).

How can I do this?

Can this be accomplished without having to first specify/generate CSS for all classes?

Comment: Do the elements possibly have several classes, just one (or several) of which may match the clicked element's classes?

Comment: Each item only has a single class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution dynamically injects styles based on the selected class. It uses a CSS attribute selector coupled with a child selector to set the highlighting.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".outer > div");

Array.from(divs).forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    const selectedClass = element.className;
    document.querySelector(".outer").dataset.selected = selectedClass;
    document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("style"), {
      textContent: `[data-selected=${selectedClass}] .${selectedClass} {background-color: yellow}`
    }));
  });
});
```

```css
.outer > div { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="apples">apples</div>
  <div class="birds">birds</div>
  <div>No class</div>
  <div class="apples">apples</div>
  <div class="birds">birds</div>
  <div class="pines">pines</div>
  <div class="pines">pines</div>
  <div class="birds">birds</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just for my education: Does this code leak the style elements?

Comment: @Ark-kun Not totally sure what you mean exactly. This code will create new `<style></style>` tags each time a `div` containing a `class` is clicked and inject them to the end of the `body`. One optimization might be to clear out and reuse one pair of `<style></style>` instead of creating new ones each click.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible to do it exactly how you describe it. The following is possible using `:focus-within` though:

```css
.main:focus-within .a {  
  background: red;
}

.a,
.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.a {
  background: yellow;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <button class="a"></button>
  <button class="b"></button>
  <button class="a"></button>
  <button class="b"></button>
  <button class="a"></button>
  <button class="b"></button>
</div>
```

The downside is that `.a` elements also get a `red` background when you actually are focussing on a `.b` element. Also you need to be using elements that are able to focus on.

Comment: > Can this be accomplished without having to first specify/generate CSS for all classes?